# How to get data between two columns in datatable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, between

If i have two data tables like this :

**1-penaltyrule**

```
  ser  from-min  to-min  pen
   1     1         55     1
   2     56        90     2
   3     91        null   3
```

**2- penaltyEmp**

```
   ser  emp  tot-min 
    1   782   2
    2   672   67
    3   677   92
    4   56    7
```

---

I want to get the pen for each user with LINQ

i mean where `tot-min` **BETWEEN** `from-min` **AND** `to-min` **SELECT** 
`pen`

I want data table with the following result :

```
emp   pen
782   1
672   2
677   3
56    1
```

Comment: Any effort to solve it? How about create an sql query _does_ this and fill a DataTable with it?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < penaltyEmp.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(penaltyEmp.Rows[i]["tot-min"].ToString()))
                    {
                    penaltyEmp.Rows[i]["latepen"]=penaltyrule.AsEnumerable().Where(int.Parse(penaltyEmp.Rows[i]["tot-min"].ToString())=>
                    }
                }`

Comment: What if there are multiple?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `multiple` of what?

Comment: @just_name: multiple matching rules

Comment: no the rules are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
var penaltyEmps = penaltyEmp.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ser = r.Field<int>("ser"), emp=r.Field<int>("emp"), tot_min=r.Field<int>("tot-min"), row = r });
var penaltyrules = penaltyrule.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { ser = r.Field<int>("ser"), from_min=r.Field<int>("from-min"), to_min=r.Field<int>("to-min"), row = r });

DataTable tblResult = penaltyEmps
    .Select(x => new
    {
        penaltyEmp = x,
        matchingRules = penaltyrules.Where(x2 => x.tot_min >= x2.from_min && x.tot_min <= x2.to_min)
    })
    .Where(x => x.matchingRules.Any())
    .Select(x => x.penaltyEmp.row)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in LINQ for you: (Don't forget to include the System.Linq namespace).

```
var results = from emp in context.penaltyEmp
                  join rule in context.penaltyRule on emp.ser equals rule.ser
                  where emp.tot-min > rule.from-min && emp.tot-min < rule.to-min
                  select new { emp = emp.emp, pen = rule.pen };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if you are using EF

```
   var data=(from a in db.penaltyEmp
             select new{
                  emp= a.emp,
                  pen= db.penaltyrule.Where(d=>d.from-min>a.tot-min && d.to-min==null?true:(d.to-min>a.tot-min)).Select(d=>d.pen).firstOrDefault()
                 });
```