# Select Value between two column from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable. I need to fetch a certain column value based on the user input. For example, lets say the datatable has three column intpkdata,intFrom,intTo 
Here is my some code,

```
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["intpkdata"] = new Random().Next(0, 99999).ToString();
                drCurrentRow["intFrom"] = txtFrom.Text;
                drCurrentRow["intTo"] = txtTo.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["Pcidata"] = dtCurrentTable;
                gdvpciData.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                gdvpciData.DataBind();
```

Requirement :

if intFrom/intTo data is already exist in datatable then msg should come.Pleas see the image for records

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz3yY.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data between two columns in datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786195/how-to-get-data-between-two-columns-in-datatable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
string fromValue = "some value";
string toValue = "some value";

if(dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => fromValue == row.Field<string>("intFrom") && toValue == row.Field<string>("intTo")))
{
 //exists 
}
```

see this ques. 
[Check if value exists in dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703320/check-if-value-exists-in-datatable)

[Check if String / Record exists in DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961059/check-if-string-record-exists-in-datatable)

Comment: I am getting this error " Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'  "

Comment: what is the data type of `intFrom` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot,Working fine you save my lot of time bro. Actually i forgot to convert.

Comment: @ImranAzam Welcome :)

Comment: How to search data between intfrom and intTo column, let say first time i have added 10 to 30 and next time i am trying to  add value 15 to 40 then msg should come bcz 15 is already exist in between 10 to 30 any idea how to achieve this task @Ajay Punekar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109749/discussion-between-imran-azam-and-ajay-punekar).

Answer (score 0):

Let `txtFrom` and `txtTo` be the two values, that have to be checked in the `intFrom` row and `intTo` columns respectively.(assuming that are having values 10 and 30). So the filter condition will be as follows, if the count `> 0` means there are such rows existing in the table so the message can be printed.

```
string txtFrom = "10";
string txtTo = "30";
if (dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("intFrom") == txtFrom && row.Field<string>("intTo") == txtTo).Count() > 0)
{
    // Display message here that it already exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code....

```
{

   String strName = "name";

    bool contains = dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => strName == row.Field<String>("intFrom"));

    String strName2 = "name";

    bool contains2 = dtCurrentTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => strName2 == row.Field<String>("intTo"));

    if (contains && contains2)
    {
        // Do your code
    }
}
```